# django tastypie custom authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, authentication, tastypie

so i have this implementation of django tastypie and jquery ajax post basic authentication and it works:

tastypie:

```
class RatingResource(ModelResource):
    city = fields.ForeignKey(CityResource, 'city')
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Rating.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rating'
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

query:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth('yuri','y')); 
    },
    success: function (){
        alert("200"); 
    },
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
  });
```

My question is, how do i write my own custom authentication??

i have tried to follow this: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#implementing-your-own-authentication-authorization but i am getting a 401 unathourized.
Here is my failed attempt to do this:

```
class SillyAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        if 'test' in request.user.username:
          return True

        return False

    # Optional but recommended
    def get_identifier(self, request):
        return request.user.username

class RatingResource(ModelResource):
    city = fields.ForeignKey(CityResource, 'city')
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Rating.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rating'
        authentication = SillyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()


function make_base_auth(user, password) {
            var tok = user + ':' + password;
            var hash = btoa(tok);
            return "Silly " + hash;
          }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth('yuri','y')); 
    },
    success: function (){
        alert("200"); 
    },
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
  });
```

How can i adapt my code with a custom authentication?

Comment: It would be far more useful for you to post the code that does not work instead of the code that does.

Comment: i added now above the code that does not work. any ideas?

Comment: which version of tastypie do you use? Authentication/authorization changed its api in some recent version, so be sure you use right documentation. Also - what is the `url` which AJAX targets to? Try add some debug `print` statements into Auth class code, where it fails to see if it is really fails in given place and not elsewhere.

Comment: i am using tastypie 0.9.14 the latest.. i think i saw the right documentation. the url is var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/smart/rating/';